# Angular: modal window disappears when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog

my contact form opens as modal

```
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private contactService: ContactService) { }
close() {this.activeModal.dismiss('Cross click');}
}
```

I invoke it from here

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
  ngOnInit() {  }  
  openContactForm() {
    this.modalService.open(ContactFormComponent, { windowClass: 'contact-modal', size: 'xl' });   
  }
}
```

and in my `app.component.html`

```
<div class="col-12 text text-center" style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="openContactForm()">Contact Us</div>
```

Clicking outside the contact form area hides it - where and how can I set it to static so it can be closed only from the close or send button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `backdrop` property to 'static'

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModal

Comment: where should I place it - I've tried in different places and nothing works

Comment: @KukulaMula this.modalService.open(ContactFormComponent, {windowClass: 'contact-modal', size: 'xl', backdrop: 'static'});

Comment: thanks that did the trick :)